# Difference between $rootScope.$on vs $scope.$on

Tags: angularjs, events

Can someone help me understand the way when we should use `$rootScope.$on` and `$scope.$on`.

I know that its mostly for hearing different scope ($rootScope and $scope).

My query is for below Scenario:

> Shall I use : **$rootScope.$emit** with **$rootScope.$on**

OR

> Shall I prefer: **$rootScope.$broadcast** with **$scope.$on**
>   I know this will be not a good option as it'll broadcast to all `$scope` obj.

OR

> Shall I go for: **$rootScope.$broadcast** with **$rootScope.$on**

As you can see, I need to handle event on $rootScope level.

**What is the difference in above 3 implementations ?**

Comment: You still need an answer for this? I could create one.

Comment: @lin: yes plz, that would be great. My doubt still stands

Comment: Done =) please check my answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a good questions and there is an explanation for you.

### First of all note that:

- `$scope.on('event');` will listen to `$scope.$broadcast('event')` & `$rootScope.$broadcast('event')`
- `$rootScope.on('event');` will listen to `$rootScope.$broadcast('event')` & `$rootScope.$emit('event')`

### Next you need to note that:

- `$scope.on();` will be destroyed automatically when the controller loses it representation in view or component (getting destroyed).
- You need to destroy `$rootScope.$on()` manually.

#### >> Example of how to destroy `$rootScope.on()`:

```
//bind event
var registerScope = $rootScope.$on('someEvent', function(event) {
    console.log("fired");
});

// auto clean up `$rootScope` listener when controller getting destroy
// listeners will be destroyed by calling the returned function like registerScope();
$scope.$on('$destroy', registerScope);
```

#### >>> Since Angular v1.5 we can use component lifecycle to manage init and destroys in a nice way:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {

  var registerScope = null;

  this.$onInit = function () {
    //register rootScope event
    registerScope = $rootScope.$on('someEvent', function(event) {
        console.log("fired");
    });
  }

  this.$onDestroy = function () {
    //unregister rootScope event by calling the return function
    registerScope();
  }
});
```

#### This [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/qeXhk072kzpKn1r3zvcw?p=preview) will show you the different behaviors of `$scope.on()` and  `$rootScope.on()`.

By switching the view in this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/qeXhk072kzpKn1r3zvcw?p=preview) the controller will be rebinded to your view. The `$rootScope.on();` event is binded every time you switch a view without destroying the event bindings of the view before. In that way the `$rootScope.on()` listeners will be stacked/multiplied. This will not happen to the `$scope.on()` bindings because it will be destroyed by switching the view (losing the E2E binding representation in DOM -> controller is destroyed).

### The difference between `$emit` & `$broadcast` is:

- `$rootScope.$emit()` events only triggers `$rootScope.$on()` events.
- `$rootScope.$broadcast()` will trigger `$rootScope.$on()` &  `$scope.on()`events (pretty much everthing hear this event).
- `$scope.$emit()` will trigger all `$scope.$on`, all its parents (scopes in parent controllers) and `$rootScope.$on()`.
- `$scope.$broadcast` will only trigger `$scope` and its children (scopes in child controllers).

#### Additional Links

- [Do you need to unbind $scope.$on in $scope $destroy event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247286/do-you-need-to-unbind-scope-on-in-scope-destroy-event/42247423#42247423)

Comment: I have corrected one of ur points. Here is the supporting plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/smfu2gX1rNGxQQYJdHbF?p=preview

Comment: So, using `$rootScope.$emit()` and `$rootScope.$on()` is better if handling on rootscope level, but I'll have to keep in mind that it has to be destroyed properly to avoid memory leaks. isn't it?

Comment: @Samuel Thanks! I added some information about what happends if you don't destroy them.

Comment: Amazing example. Thanks !

Comment: @Codiee Your statement is wrong: https://plnkr.co/edit/7cDpMatVs4LIN7f93HHG?p=preview - `$rootScope.on('event');` will listen to `$rootScope.$broadcast('event')` & `$rootScope.$emit('event')`

Comment: Hi, that comment was incompletely posted on enter, My contradiction was 1.$rootScope.on('event'); will listen to $rootScope.$broadcast('event') & $rootScope.$emit('event') 2.$rootScope.$broadcast() will trigger $rootScope.$on() &  $scope.on()events (pretty much everthing hear this event). so .$rootScope.$broadcast('event') can also trigger $scope.$on ?

Comment: Hi, If I want to trigger $on to another controller then it will work?