# Do you need to unbind $scope.$on in $scope $destroy event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have directive that bind event using $on do I need to remove that binding when scope is destroyed, or is it done automatically? Also do I need to call $element.off?

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        $element.on('load', function() {
            $element[0].contentWindow.focus();
        });
        $scope.$on('iframe:focus', function() {
            $element[0].contentWindow.focus();
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`$scope.$on()` **listeners will be destroyed / cleaned up automatically** when it loses its representation due to E2E binding in your view. Note that this will not happen for `$rootScope.$on()` bindings. You could also take a look at the [$scope documentation of AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).

#### Answer in a few words:

- `$scope.$on();` will be destroyed automatically.
- You need to destroy `$rootScope.$on()` manually.

#### The documentation says:

> Scope Destruction - When child scopes are no longer needed , it is the
> responsibility of the child scope creator to destroy them via
> scope.$destroy() API. This is done in order to stop propagation of
> $digest calls into the child scope and allow for memory used by the
> child scope models to be reclaimed by the garbage collector.

#### Example of how to destroy `$rootScope.$on()`:

```
// bind event
const registerScope = $rootScope.$on('someEvent', function(event) {
  console.log("fired");
});

// clean up
$scope.$on('$destroy', registerScope);
```

---

#### This [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/qeXhk072kzpKn1r3zvcw?p=preview) will show you the different behaviors of `$scope.$on()` and  `$rootScope.$on()`.

By switching the view in this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/qeXhk072kzpKn1r3zvcw?p=preview) the controller will be rebinded to your view. The `$rootScope.$on();` event is binded every time you switch a view without destroying the event bindings of the view before. In that way the `$rootScope.$on()` listeners will be stacked/multiplied. This will not happen to the `$scope.$on()` bindings because it will be destroyed by switching the view (losing the E2E binding representation in DOM).

---

#### Note that:

- `$scope.$on('event');` will listen to `$scope.$broadcast('event')` & `$rootScope.$broadcast('event')`
- `$rootScope.$on('event');` will only listen to `$rootScope.$broadcast('event')`

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't need to remove that binding. It will be removed when the scope is destroyed. However if you bind event to $rootScope always remember to unbind it! It can be done easily like this:

```
        var unregister = $rootScope.$on('eventName', function(e) {
            //doSomething
        });


        $scope.$on('$destroy', unregister);
```

Answer (score 3):

> Scope Destruction - When child scopes are no longer needed , it is the
>   responsibility of the child scope creator to destroy them via
>   scope.$destroy()API. This is done in order to stop propagation of
>   $digest calls into the child scope and allow for memory used by the
>   child scope models to be reclaimed by the garbage collector.

**Listeners registered to scopes and elements are automatically cleaned up when they are destroyed**, but if you registered a listener on a service, rootScope or registered a listener on a DOM node that isn't being deleted, you'll have to clean it up yourself or you risk introducing a memory leak.

When `$scope.$destroy()` is executed it will remove all listeners registered via `$on` **on *that* `$scope`**. It will not remove DOM elements or any attached event handlers added through :

```
element.on('click', function (event) {
  ...
});
```

More information about the angular.element https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Answer (score 0):

> do I need to remove that binding when scope is destroyed,

The listeners are removed automatically by re-initializing `$$listeners`. Here is the relevant part from source code:

```
  $destroy: function() {
    ...
    // Disable listeners, watchers and apply/digest methods
    this.$destroy = this.$digest = this.$apply = this.$evalAsync = this.$applyAsync = noop;
    this.$on = this.$watch = this.$watchGroup = function() { return noop; };
    this.$$listeners = {};
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

> Also do I need to call $element.off?

No, they should be removed by a browser when a DOM node associated with `$element` is destroyed.