# AngularJS broadcast event is not listening inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive, broadcast

I'm trying to export some data to xls, pdf, get a example on by using AngularJS `$broadcast` events - [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HmKBjYmJNjp8mPzIlg52?p=preview).

**This is my controller:**

```
admin.controller('ctrlReuniaoRelatorioDetalhe', ['$scope', '$http', '$controller', '$window', 'baseURL', 'blockUI', function($scope, $http, $controller, $window, baseURL, blockUI) {
  angular.extend(this, $controller('BaseListController', {
    $scope: $scope
  }));

  $scope.Formulario = "ReuniaoRelatorioDetalheViewModelForm";
  $scope.dataemissao = new Date();
  ctrlReuniaoRelatorioDetalhe = $scope;
  ctrlReuniaoRelatorioDetalhe.http = $http;


  $scope.reportData = [{
    "EmployeeID": "1234567",
    "LastName": "Lastname",
    "FirstName": "First name",
    "Salary": 1000
  }, {
    "EmployeeID": "11111111",
    "LastName": "Lastname 1",
    "FirstName": "First name 1",
    "Salary": 2000
  }, {
    "EmployeeID": "222222222",
    "LastName": "Lastname 2",
    "FirstName": "First name 2",
    "Salary": 3000
  }, {
    "EmployeeID": "333333333",
    "LastName": "Lastname 3",
    "FirstName": "First name 3",
    "Salary": 4000
  }];

  $scope.exportAction = function(option) {

    switch (option) {
      case 'pdf':
        $scope.$broadcast('export-pdf', {});
        break;
      case 'excel':
        $scope.$broadcast('export-excel', {});
        break;
      case 'doc':
        $scope.$broadcast('export-doc', {});
        break;
      case 'csv':
        $scope.$broadcast('export-csv', {});
        break;
      default:
        console.log('no event caught');
    }
  }
}]);
```

**This is my directive:**

```
 app.directive('exportTable', function() {
   var link = function($scope, elm, attr) {
     $scope.$on('export-pdf', function(e, d) {
       elm.tableExport({
         type: 'pdf',
         escape: false
       });
     });
     $scope.$on('export-excel', function(e, d) {
       elm.tableExport({
         type: 'excel',
         escape: false
       });
     });
     $scope.$on('export-doc', function(e, d) {
       elm.tableExport({
         type: 'doc',
         escape: false
       });
     });
     $scope.$on('export-csv', function(e, d) {
       elm.tableExport({
         type: 'csv',
         escape: false
       });
     });
   }
   return {
     restrict: 'C',
     link: link
   }
 });
```

I dont have any idea why `$scope.$on()` in my directive is not listening to my event. The `$scope.exportAction` is working but when "broadcast" is fired, nothing happends.

Comment: use `$rootScope.$broadcast` (don't forget to inject `$rootScope`, it's not global)

Comment: i'm noob on angular, how i do this? where did i insert this line? thanks!

Comment: **1.** `admin.controller('...', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '...', function ($scope,$rootScope,...` **2.** `$rootScope.$broadcast('export-pdf', {});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cover/analyze two scenarios here. Please check both working examples in this answer and make yourself understood how broadcasting in AngularJS works.

*This links will help you to dig deeper into broadcast events:*

- [Do you need to unbind $scope.$on in $scope $destroy event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247286/do-you-need-to-unbind-scope-on-in-scope-destroy-event/42247423#42247423)
- [Difference between $rootScope.$on vs $scope.$on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41632318/difference-between-rootscope-on-vs-scope-on/43638652#43638652)

---

**Use `$scope.$broadcast()` when your directive is a child of your controller where the event is fired. -> [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rkvyjL2z/)**

### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';

    $scope.clickMe = function () {
       $scope.$broadcast('test');
    }
});

myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$on('test', function () {
            console.log('hello world');
        })
      }
    }
});
```

### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button ng-click="clickMe()">
    Click Me
  </button>
  <div my-directive></div>
</div>
```

---

**Use `$rootScope.$broadcast()` when your directive is not a child of your controller where the event is fired. -> [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cooubaax/)**

### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';

    $scope.clickMe = function () {
       $rootScope.$broadcast('test');
    }
});

myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, $rootScope) {
        scope.$root.$on('test', function () {
            console.log('hello world');
        })
      }
    }
});
```

### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button ng-click="clickMe()">
    Click Me
  </button>
</div>
<div my-directive></div>
```

Comment: on app.directive, i change to
admin.directive, and worked!!
Thanks all :D