# AngularJS - $rootScope.$on - Multiple execution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my `$onInit()` I pick up the propagation event:

```
  $onInit() {
    this.$rootScope.$on('CANCELLED', (event) => {
      this.EventService.getEventsCurrentUser('own')
        .then((result) => {
          this.ownEvents = result
        })
      })
  }
```

How can I stop the propagation at one time ?

Comment: what you meant by at one time?

Comment: Don't register the event on the rootscope. Register it on the scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "unregister" `$rootScope` events manually by calling the return function. You can do it with the component lifecycle by using `this.$onDestroy`. `$rootScope` events getting binded again and again each time `$rootScope.$on()` is executed. Thats why your events getting called multiple times.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {

  var registerScope = null;

  this.$onInit = function () {
    //register rootScope event
    registerScope = $rootScope.$on('CANCELLED', function(event) {
        console.log("fired");
    });
  }

  this.$onDestroy = function () {
    //unregister rootScope event by calling the return function
    registerScope();
  }
});
```

Please also check this answers which will help you to understand the logic behind `$rootScope` and `$scope` events:

- [How to use component lifecycles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150289/running-angularjs-initialization-code-when-view-is-loaded/43301416#43301416)
- [Difference between $rootScope.$on vs $scope.$on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41632318/difference-between-rootscope-on-vs-scope-on/43638652#43638652)

Comment: You have an idea why it never goes into the $onDestroy method ?

Comment: @MouadEnnaciri Are you using `ui-router`?

Comment: @in Yes, on the other hand enters the method when I change the route

Comment: @MouadEnnaciri `$onDestroy` does not work with `ui-router` binded controllers because this event is not delegated by `ui-router`. Please check https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3043 & https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3043 you could create a component instead of a controller to make work or use `$scope.$on('$destroy')`. Glad to help ya

Comment: @MouadEnnaciri any feedback?

Comment: I enter the `$onDestroy` method when I change my route, it's good I think?