# Angularjs ui-route correct implementation for multiple views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, multiple-views, nested-views

I would like to implement a page like this
[image]

I have the following folder structure:

```
-root/
--root.controller.js
--root.module.js
--root.routes.js
--root.html
--filters/
----filters.controller.js
----filters.module.js
----filters.routes.js
----filters.html
--tableData/
----tableData.controller.js
----tableData.module.js
----tableData.routes.js
----tableData.html
--graph/
----graph.controller.js
----graph.module.js
----graph.routes.js
----graph.html
```

I would like to know the best approach in order to manage call from each controller in the best way.
I mean, from filters, I can change selection on dropdown or update other fields values, and then I would update data on tabledata. And if I change selection on tabledata I would update graph.
Root url is '/root/{itemId}' and I cannot add some other value on querystring.
How can I manage internal variables and methods?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, it's better to go for events `$emit` , `$broadcast` & `on` to achieve the same.

As I can see, you are having independent controllers with no relationship with  most of the the other controllers.

Few suggestions to implement it:

1. use `$rootScope.$emit` and `$rootScope.on` if they controllers have no relationship. Make sure you are removing it manually though (can be ignored if the app is not too heavy but should be kept in mind). [This link will be surely helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41632318/difference-between-rootscope-on-vs-scope-on) . **Eg:**

> If the filter is changed, an event `filter-changed` will be triggered. The `graph.controller` and `table.controller` will be informed and will render the UI accordingly.

2. Create a `messaging` service from where the controllers will subscribe and unsubscribe the `events`. That will keep numbers of `events` in check. You'll be aware of how many events have actually been created in the application.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I agree with your approach. About messagging service, did you know about a good npm angularjs plugin that implements that?

Comment: @Saledan , no I am not aware of it. You can create your own service. It won’t be difficult. Best is to start without a service and once you create 2-3 controllers, you can move those event logic to a service. Don’t try to implement everything from start if you are not clear but keep this point in your mind. ;). Mark it as an answer if it has helped